# Belongs to one through relation in Laravel 5.4. What is the best way?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have these 3 entities in my system:

1. Questions
2. Scales
3. Ranks

A question may belong to no scale but can belong to maximum 1 scale only. A scale has many ranks. This means that a question belongs to many ranks through scales table. I want to retrieve all ranks (if any) when retrieving a question.

How to achieve that?

Till now this is what I have done:

created `questions table`
created `scales table`
created `ranks table` with `scale_id` as foreign key
created `question_scales` table with `question_id` and `scale_id` as foreign keys.

How to fetch questions with associated ranks?

Comment: As per as I understand your question, I don't think you need question_scales table as question can relate to none or maximum one scale.You can add scale_id to questions table.

Comment: @VishalTarkar Yes, I could have done that but that is a bad design. I did not want a lot of `null` values in scale_id column. Secondly, in future, I might need to have some more parameters added with question_scale combination, that is why I decided to create a new table instead of adding a column